# Cabal after build command (Haskell build system)

Tags: haskell, build, compilation, cabal, post-processing

Is it possible to tell Cabal to run some command after building the application?

I want for example to generate with a script some `.hs` files and after building to copy some other files to `dist/build/app` directory.

Comment: Is this for end users or just for yourself? It's always possible (if hackish) to simply wrap `cabal whatever` in a script that does stuff and invokes cabal on it's own. It's fairly easy to have it route arguments straight to cabal too

Comment: I would lie to do it "the production ready way" for end users. Such script is not bad for end users also - but as I see (based on the answer of @RanjitJhala) - it is possible by default :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Take a look at `postInst` and related types/operations.

[Distribution.Simple.UserHooks](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/Cabal/latest/doc/html/Distribution-Simple-UserHooks.html#v%3apostInst)

Here's a quick example, you can hoogle the relevant operations to figure out more.
This executes the various .sh scripts, copies files etc. AFTER the cabal build. 
`absoluteInstallDirs` tells you where cabal is putting the other files, should 
you need it.

Hope this helps!

```
import Distribution.Simple
import Distribution.Simple.LocalBuildInfo
import System.Process
import System.Exit

main = defaultMainWithHooks fixpointHooks

fixpointHooks  = simpleUserHooks { postInst = buildAndCopyFixpoint } 

buildAndCopyFixpoint _ _ pkg lbi 
  = do putStrLn $ "Post Install: " ++ show binDir -- , libDir)
       executeShellCommand "./configure"
       executeShellCommand "./build.sh"
       executeShellCommand $ "chmod a+x external/fixpoint/fixpoint.native "
       executeShellCommand $ "cp external/fixpoint/fixpoint.native " ++ binDir
       executeShellCommand $ "cp external/z3/lib/libz3.* " ++ binDir
  where 
    allDirs     = absoluteInstallDirs pkg lbi NoCopyDest
    binDir      = bindir allDirs ++ "/"

executeShellCommand cmd   = putStrLn ("EXEC: " ++ cmd) >> system cmd >>= check
  where 
    check (ExitSuccess)   = return ()
    check (ExitFailure n) = error $ "cmd: " ++ cmd ++ " failure code " ++ show n
fixpointHooks  = simpleUserHooks { postInst = buildAndCopyFixpoint }
```

Comment: This comes with a big warning that Distribution.Simple.UserHooks might change/break stuff, however it's probably the best you got.

Comment: I understand this stuff goes to `Setup.hs`?

Comment: @jozefg I'm really afraid of what you've told :(

Comment: @danilo2 this is something that bit me recently, and I don't think either package maintainers or the cabal developers fully understand the issue: because you can't do CPP conditional compilation based on Cabal lib version, it means that when Cabal changes some API you're using (as they do for `Distribution.Simple.*`) the package maintainer must either restrict the dependency to old Cabal, or go with the new version and break all compatibility with older Cabal. see: https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/18